# player plays two times on first click

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a tough time I have a code where you click on a image and if it possible to move it to next cell the it should move

```
function changecell(a){
    var moved=false;
    if(a%3 !=0) {
      if(ij[a-1]==0) {
         moved=true;
         if(moved==true) {
                no=firstmove++;                 
            move.innerHTML = no;
            playTick();
            }
            swap(a-1,a);
      }
   }

    if((a+1)%3 !=0 && moved==false) {
      if(ij[a+1]==0) {
            moved=true;
         if(moved==true) {
            no=firstmove++;                  
            move.innerHTML = no;
            playTick();
            }
            swap(a+1,a);
      }
   }
}

function playTick() {
    document.getElementById('tickSound').play();
}

function swap(x1,x2) {
    var temp=ij[x1];
   ij[x1]=ij[x2];
   ij[x2]=temp;
   var p = eval("document.images.i"+x1);
   p.src="images1/"+ij[x1]+".png";
   p = eval("document.images.i"+x2);
   p.src="images1/"+ij[x2]+".png";
}
```

my problem is for first click the sound plays for two times and then after that it plays once as it is supposed to play.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

**EDIT:**

I did put an `alert()` in the `if(moved==true)` loop the alert shows only for once but sound plays twice. Suppose the `if(moved==true)` was getting executed again wouldn't I get another `alert()`?

Comment: you provide not enough code so we can identify the problem. perhaps you initialised move to true instead of false in the beginning bit that's all just some helpless guessing.

Comment: I can't say if this is the answer, but my first conclusion would be that (not seeing the swap or playTick functions) you are setting var moved to false in one of those functions. Also, I am assuming the variable moved is global, and we you just seeing your local implementation in the code you pasted. - So, it is also passing the second root *if* conditional. Thus, it goes thru the first, fires animation, then goes to the second.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that both the `if` conditions are being satisfied on the first run so the `playTick()` method is being called twice. Without knowing the value of `a`, i cannot be sure.

Comment: the values of a can be a number between 0 - 5 presently. For each image a number is given.